Automatically navigate to next highlighted error on compile
In IntelliJ IDEA there's an option under Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler called "Automatically show first error in editor" that jumps to the correct line in the source code on compilation errors.
I cannot find the same setting in JetBrains Rider, so when I compile C# and there's an error I have to use Navigate > Next Highlighted Error (or the keyboard shortcut) every time to navigate to the code with the first error.
Is there any setting in JetBrains Rider so this will happen automatically?
